# Replace String with Array of Objects

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to replace a string constant with an array of object.

What I have is

```
string test = "{\"property\":\"#replacedValue#\"}";

var array = someObject.where(x=>something).ToArray();

test = test.Replace("#replacedValue#",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array));
```

output is coming as

```
{"property":"[{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}]"}
```

Array is being replaced as string

what I want is

```
 {"property":[{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"},{"name":"value"}]};
```

I am using .net core 3.1

Comment: JSON is a string format. The problem here is you're replacing only the `#replacedValue#` value, leaving the surrounding quotes in place. Replace the entire string instead (`"#replacedValue#"`) escaping the double quotes

Comment: `string test = {"property":"#replacedValue#"};` this is not valid C#. What your probably have is `string test = "{\"property\":\"#replacedValue#\"}";`

Comment: code updated with valid string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your json string into `JObject` and replace property value:

```
string test = @"{""property"":""#replacedValue#""}";

var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(test);
jObj["property"] = new JArray(new[] {1,2,3,4});
Console.WriteLine(jObj.ToString());
```

will print:

```
{
  "property": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ]
}
```